# Branch of power function

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that there exists a branch in ($\mathbb{C}-[0,1]$) for function $f(z)=z^a(1-z)^b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a+b=1$.

So I was thinking this way:

$$f(z)=z^a(1-z)^b=e^{\operatorname{Log}(z^a(1-z)^b)}=e^{a\operatorname{Log}z}e^{b\operatorname{Log}(1-z)}$$

So if I could come up with branch for $\operatorname{Log}z$ and $\operatorname{Log}(1-z)$ at the same time on $\mathbb{C}-[0,1]$ then it would be it, but I don't think it is possible even for $\operatorname{Log}z$, because then we have to get rid of a whole halfline in order for branch to be continuous.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/763486/42969.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(z) = z^a(1-z)^b$ has such a branch, then all closed path integrals in $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$ of the following would be integer multiples of $2\pi i$:
$$
         \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{az^{a-1}(1-z)^b-bz^{a}(1-z)^{b-1}}{z^a(1-z)^b} \\
         = \frac{a}{z}-\frac{b}{1-z}=\frac{a}{z}+\frac{b}{z-1}.
$$
This does work because $a+b=1$. Up to a multiplicative constant, the desired function is
$$
        f(z)=C\exp\left\{ \int_{-i}^{z}\frac{a}{w}+\frac{b}{w-1}dw\right\}
$$
where the path from $-i$ to $z$ is any path in $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$, and where $C$ is chosen so that $f(-i)$ is correct.